como reemplazar los resultados de una consulta python
Buenas tardes antes de nada, agradecer por detenerse en leer mi consulta.
En python estoy haciendo un llamando a una API y cuando traigo la información un campo que es el de info me trae datos con valore de \r y \n generándome saltos de líneas no deseados en mi resultado, deseo que todo salga en una sola línea.
deseo reemplazar o eliminar los saltos de línea y el \r, adjunto mi código actual.
res_info=requests.get("https://www.dominio.com"}
")

datainfo = res_info.json()

 for items in datainfo:
        id = items['id']
        ip = items['ip']
        hostname = items['hostname']
        info = items['info']

    datos = {
        'id' : id,
        'ip' : ip,
        'hostname' : hostname,
        'info' : info,
        }

         print(datos)

el resultado que me sales el siguiente:
{'id': 1994, 'ip': '10.10.1.1', 'hostname': 'DESK', 'info': 'host: https://www.dominio.com\r\nuser: user1\r\npass: user1'}

y quisiera que el resultado sea:
{'id': 1994, 'ip': '10.10.1.1', 'hostname': 'DESK', 'info': 'host: https://www.dominio.com  user: user1 pass: user1'}


Probablemente str.splitlines o un equivalente del lado del sql te sea util

Si no tienes control sobre la API, una vez que tengas la consulta puedes simplemente reemplazar los saltos de linea con un espacio, bien solo sobre la cadena info, sobre más de una clave o sobre la cadena del JSON directamente.
Usando str.replace()
>>> info.replace("\r\n", " ")
'host: https://www.dominio.com user: user1 pass: user1'


Reemplazará cualquier aparición de \r\n en cualquier posición por un espacio.
Es rígido, en el sentido de que solo reemplazará \r\n, no te va a substituir si tienes un solo \n o un solo \r o \r\r, \n\n, etc

Usar str.splitlines() junto a str.join()
>>> " ".join(info.splitlines())
'host: https://www.dominio.com user: user1 pass: user1'


Substituirá cada representación de nueva linea soportada (\r, \r\n, \n) con un espacio. Es decir \n\n se reemplaza con dos espacios, \r\n con uno, \r\n\r con dos, etc.

Los saltos de linea al final de la cadena serán eliminados pero no se reemplazarán.

Los saltos de linea al inicio de la cadena se reemplazarán por un espacio.


Usando regex con re.sub()
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", " ", info)
'host: https://www.dominio.com user: user1 pass: user1'


En este caso substituirá cualquier combinación de \r o \n encadenadas o no (\r, \n, \r\n, \n\n\n, \r\n\n, etc) con un solo espacio.


str.strip() te puede también ser útil para eliminar los espacios en blanco al inicio y final de la cadena antes de aplicar la substitución, aunque en tu ejemplo no existe este caso.
